# Get the list of installed extensions for Pimcore v5 in PHP

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

I have to write an extension (plugin/bundle) which has to check if 3 other extensions are installed and enabled. I searched for a way to ask Pimcore  v5 about all installed extensions and their status. Is there is anyone who can point to some information in Pimcore docs or who knows how this can by done?

Answer (score 2):

Various Methods like

- [isInstalled](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/4c986d60d890898e466533a21dfd29bde2acb9f6/lib/Extension/Bundle/PimcoreBundleManager.php#L552)
- [isEnabled](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/4c986d60d890898e466533a21dfd29bde2acb9f6/lib/Extension/Bundle/PimcoreBundleManager.php#L428)
- [canBeInstalled](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/4c986d60d890898e466533a21dfd29bde2acb9f6/lib/Extension/Bundle/PimcoreBundleManager.php#L512)

etc to check the states of the bundles are available in **[PimcoreBundleManager](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/4c986d60d890898e466533a21dfd29bde2acb9f6/lib/Extension/Bundle/PimcoreBundleManager.php)** .

For more info: Take a look at the implementation of these methods in **[EnableCommand](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/89bc89e71e3d33b4c4b8ac80aee639a974bcc374/bundles/CoreBundle/Command/Bundle/EnableCommand.php)**